# Open Excel file and call macro from PowerBuilder

Tags: excel, powerbuilder

I'm trying to call a macro with certain parameters from PowerBuilder but it's not working.

This is the code i'm using:

```
OLEObject ole_object
ole_object = CREATE OLEObject

string ls_reportInPath = "C:\Prevalidador_DIAN_Tributario_2011_v1.4\Prevalidador.xls"
string ls_macroname = "Prevalidador.xls!modXML.cargarXML_General"
string ls_xml = "C:\Users\...\Desktop\010100107201100000001.xml"
string ls_file = "C:\Users\...\Desktop\excel_file.xls"

IF ole_object.ConnectToNewObject("excel.application") = 0 THEN
    ole_object.Object.Application.DisplayAlerts = "False"
    ole_object.workbooks.Open(ls_reportInPath) //Open the .xls file
Else
    MessageBox('OLE Error','Unable to start an OLE server process!',Exclamation!)
END IF

ole_object.Object.Application.Run (ls_macroname)

ole_object.Application.Quit()
ole_object.DisconnectObject()
DESTROY ole_object
```

Also, I'd like to show the excel sheet the user.

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

The error is common to two lines:

```
ole_object.Object.Application.DisplayAlerts = "False"
ole_object.Object.Application.Run (ls_macroname)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel could be wrong when doing the coercion text -> bool ?

I have some code here where we do the following, without using the `Object` btw :

```
OLEObject iole_xlapp
iole_xlapp = CREATE OLEObject
li_rtn = iole_xlapp.ConnectToNewObject( "excel.application" )
//...
iole_xlapp.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `"ole_object.Object.Application.Run (ls_macroname)",`

use

```
ole_object.Application.Run (ls_macroname)
```

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but I'd lower-case the O in "Object".

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Still getting the same problem.